# Using Spock to mock Java 8 method

Tags: unit-testing, spock

I am trying to mock

```java
ZoneId customerTimeZone = extractFromCustomer(location)
  .map(someService::getZoneByChannel)
  .orElseThrow()
```

Using spock is there a way I can mock the entire `extractFromCustomer(location)...` chain to just return a `ZoneId` object?

Comment: looks like `extractFromCustomer` is private method and `getZoneByChannel` is service method, so you can just mock the `getZoneByChannel` method

Comment: Please present an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. a fully self-consistent set of sample classes + Spock spec which I can compile and run. Thank you.